# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = 3T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right) + n\log_2 n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

[image: Problem]

I've seen plenty of discussion regarding solving recurrences like this with the master theorem, but I need to solve it via back substitution. Was doing pretty good until I got stuck in the summation part.

Assumptions are that $n$ is a power of $3$ so $n = 3^k$ and hence $k = \log_3(n)$. Also $T(1) = 1$.

After substituting $3$ functions to recognize the pattern I found this general form for the recurrence:

[image: Formula 1]

And then I followed with:

[image: Formula 2]

However this is the part where I got stuck:

[image: Formula 3]

I have absolutely no idea of how to resolve that sum, I tried applying logarithm properties to get a difference instead of division and then make two separated and simplier sums, but I still couldn't find or figure out if I can use any summation identities.

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\log_3\left(\frac n{3^i}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\log_3 n-i)=k\log_3n-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i$$ hence $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\log_3\left(\frac n{3^i}\right)=k\log_3n-\frac{k(k-1)}2$$

Comment: Why are you able to take *log3(n)* out of the summation without writing it in sigma notation again? Where does the *k* multiplying that come from? D:

Comment: Because $\log_3n$ does not depend on $i$. And because there are $k$ terms in the sum. For every number $c$ independent of $i$, $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}c=c\,k$$

Comment: that means *log3(n)* could be treated as a constant? or does "constant" in this case just means not dependant on the sum index?

Comment: Either one you prefer.

Comment: also I just noticed it is log2(n/3^i) and not log3 ):

Comment: Trivial changes, similar result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will redo the work from begginning also using $\lg x=\log_2 x$ as binary logarithm.

First I will iterate the first term, then later combine it with the sum which the second term gave:$$T(n)=3T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+n\lg n$$
$$3T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)=3\left(3T\left(\frac{n}{3^2}\right)+\frac{n}{3}\lg\frac{n}{3}\right)=3^2T\left(\frac{n}{3^2}\right)+n\lg\frac{n}{3}$$
$$3^2T\left(\frac{n}{3^2}\right)=3^2\left(3T\left(\frac{n}{3^3}\right)+\frac{n}{3^2}\lg\frac{n}{3^2}\right)=3^3T\left(\frac{n}{3^3}\right)+n\lg\frac{n}{3^2}$$
$$\dots$$
$$3^{k-1}T\left(\frac{n}{3^{k-1}}\right)=3^kT\left(\frac{n}{3^k}\right)+n\lg\frac{n}{3^{k-1}}$$
The recursion ends when we hit $T(1)$, thus we can take $k$ from there:
$$T\left(\frac{n}{3^k}\right)=T(1)\Rightarrow n=3^k\Rightarrow k=\log_3n$$
$$\Rightarrow T(n)=3^k \cdot \underbrace{T(1)}_{=1}+n\lg n +n\lg\frac{n}{3}+\dots+n\lg\frac{n}{3^{k-1}}$$
$$=\underbrace{3^{\log_3 n}}_{=n} \cdot 1 +\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n \lg\frac{n}{3^{i}}=n+n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(\lg n-\lg3^{i}\right),\quad \quad a^{\log_a b}=b^{\log_a a}$$
$$=n+n\lg n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}1-n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i \cdot \lg 3, \quad \quad \lg a^b = b\lg a$$
$$=n+n\lg n \cdot k -n\lg 3 \cdot \frac{(k-1)k}{2}$$
$$=n+n\lg n \cdot \frac{\lg n}{\lg 3}-\frac{\lg 3}{2}n\left(\frac{\lg n}{\lg 3}-1\right)\frac{\lg n}{\lg 3},\quad \quad k=\log_3 n =\frac{\lg n}{\lg 3}$$
$$=n+\frac{1}{\lg 3} n\lg^2 n -\frac12 \frac{1}{\lg 3}n\lg^2 n+\frac12 n\lg n$$
$$\boxed{T(n)=n+\frac1{2\log_2 3} n\log_2^2 n +\frac12 n\log_2 n}$$

Comment: I tried to follow from where I got stuck, but I got a slightly different result. Could you check my edit at the end of my question and check if I missed something? I think you missed multiplying by *lg3* in one of the denominators, but it could be my mistake too

Comment: @MikeKatz45 Yes, I forgot to multiply there by the red factor: $$\frac{\lg 3}{2}n\left(\frac{\lg n}{\lg 3}-1\right)\frac{\lg n}{\color{red}{\lg 3}}$$
Also note that  you have a minus sign when you mutiply by $1$, thus the last term will have a plus.

Comment: Excellent thank you very much, it took me a while to follow your proceedure, but I understand everything now (:

Answer (score 0):

Considering from $T(n)-3T(\frac n3)=n\log_2 n$

$$
\mathcal{T}(\log_3 n)-3\mathcal{T}(\log_3(\frac n3))=n\log_2 n
$$

or

$$
\mathcal{T}(\log_3 n)-3\mathcal{T}(\log_3 n -1))=n\log_2 n
$$

then making $z = \log_3 n$ we have the linear difference equation

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)-3\mathcal{T}(z -1)=3^z\log_2 3^z = z 3^z\log_2 3
$$

The solution can be represented as

$$
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}_h+ \mathcal{T}_p
$$

such that

$$
\mathcal{T}_h(z)-3\mathcal{T}_h(z -1)=0\\
\mathcal{T}_p(z)-3\mathcal{T}_p(z -1)=z 3^z\log_2 3
$$

but

$$
\mathcal{T}_h(z) = C 3^{z-1}
$$

now substituting $\mathcal{T}_p(z) = C(z) 3^{z-1}$ into the particular equation (variation of constants as with DE's) we obtain

$$
C(z)-C(z-1) = z^2 3^{2-z}\log_2 3
$$

and then

$$
C(z) = \frac 12 3^{3-z}\left(3^z-z-\frac{z^2}{3}-1\right)\log_2 3
$$

and finally

$$
\mathcal{T} = C 3^{z-1}+\left( \frac 12 3^{3-z}\left(3^z-z-\frac{z^2}{3}-1\right)\log_2 3\right)3^{z-1}
$$

etc.