$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log{n}$ How can I solve this recurrence using the iteration method?
$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log{n}$
How can I solve this recurrence using the iteration method?
If anyone can solve it and show me how that would be really swell.

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085606/solving-the-recurrence-tn-3t-left-fracn3-right-n-log-2-n?noredirect=1.

Trying a few small cases yields
\begin{align}
T(3) &= 3(T(1) + \log 3)
\\
T(9) &= 3T(3) + 9 \log 9 = 9(T(1) + (1 + 2) \log 3)
\\
T(27) &= 3T(9) + 27 \log 27 = 27(T(1) + (1 + 2 + 3) \log 3)
\end{align}
So for $n$ a power of $3$, we have
$$T(n) = n\left(T(1) + \frac{1}{2}(\log_3 n)(\log_3 n + 1) (\log 3)\right).$$

As a sanity check, the master theorem implies that $T(n) = \Theta(n \log^2 n)$, which the specific solution above satisfies.

Here's one way to derive
the dolution.
Putting
$n=3^m$,
$T(n) 
= 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n\log{n}
$
becomes
$T(3^m) 
= 3T(3^{m-1}) + 3^m\log{3^m}
= 3T(3^{m-1}) + m3^m\log{3}
$.
Letting
$T(3^m)=s(m)$,
this is
$s(m)
=3s(m-1)+ m3^m\log{3}
$.
Dividing by $3^m$,
$\dfrac{s(m)}{3^m}
=\dfrac{3s(m-1)}{3^m}+ m\log{3}
=\dfrac{s(m-1)}{3^{m-1}}+ m\log{3}
$..
Finally,
letting
$r(m)=\dfrac{s(m)}{3^m}$,
this is
$r(m)
=r(m-1)+m\log(3)
$
or
$r(m)-r(m-1)=m\log(3)
$.
Summing,
$\begin{array}\\
r(m)-r(0)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} (r(k)-r(k-1))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} k\log(3)\\
&=m(m+1)\log(3)/2\\
&=cm(m+1)
\qquad\text{where }c=\log(3)/2\\
\end{array}
$
so
$r(m)=r(0)+cm(m+1)
$.
Unwinding the definitions,
$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=3^mr(m)\\
&=3^m(r(0)+cm(m+1))\\
&=3^m(s(0)+cm(m+1))\\
&=T(3^m)\\
&\text{Setting } n=3^m, m=\log_3(n)\\
T(n)
&=3^m(s(0)+cm(m+1))\\
&=n(T(1)+c\log_3(n)(\log_3(n)+1))\\
&=n(T(1)+c(\log_3^2(n)+\log_3(n)))\\
\end{array}
$
This agrees with
angryavian's solution.
